# What does the ganglia directory __SummaryInfo__ contain?

Tags: python, rrdtool, rrd, ganglia

Ganglia writes cluster matrices in rrd file and keeps under the location "**/var/lib/ganglia/rrds/ClusterName/**" (in default configuration). In the above location there are directories for different hosts in the cluster and "**__SummaryInfo__**" directory

My question is What does the directory "**__SummaryInfo__"** contain?

and How can I collect the avg matrices of all machines in the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__SummaryInfo__` contains the information you need to calculate the averages of all metric values in the cluster. The rrd files there have two data sources, `sum` for the sum of the metric values over all hosts and `num` for the number of hosts that reported that metric.

You can calculate the average by dividing `sum` by `num` in an rrdtool CDEF statement:

```
DEF:sum=nameOfYour.rrd:sum:AVERAGE  
DEF:num=nameOfYour.rrd:num:AVERAGE 
CDEF:average=sum,num,/
```

Note that data resolution will deteriorate as the data gets older (more data is added).